# What View Engine are you using with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know you can use several different view engines with ASP.NET MVC:

- ASPX, obviously
- NVelocity
- Brail
- NHaml
- et al...

The default ASPX view engine seems to make the most sense to me, coming from an ASP.NET WebForms background.

But, I wanted to get an idea of the pros and cons of each and see what most people are using.

Which does StackOverflow use?

Answer (score 11):

I use [Spark](http://dev.dejardin.org/).  It has nice flow between HTML and code.  Scott Hanselman also did a [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode30SparkAndNHamlCrazyASPNETMVCViewEngines.aspx) on it with his weekly source code review posts.  I am really digging it a lot.  One of the major features is [pre-compilation](http://dev.dejardin.org/documentation/precompiling) of your views.

Answer (score 4):

NHaml is my favorite for its terseness. People either love it or hate it, given that it looks very different from a traditional "HTML with inserted code" template system like ASPX or NVelocity.

**Edit:**

@Ben,

There are other view engines which compile down (NHaml is one), so those do support custom HTML helpers. I wouldn't be surprised to see the currently interpreted view engines all eventually end up with a compilation model eventually.

Answer (score 4):

"Which does StackOverflow use?"

Web Forms.

I asked Jeff Atwood about his decision on his Tag Soup post. He didn't reply - I think he was busy hunting down a missing closing tag ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has recently announced a new view engine: Razor.

Looks pretty interesting:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: +1 WebForms made me sad; Razor makes me happy.

Answer (score 2):

Most people on the planet will just use ASPX because that's what they know.  Another excellent benefit is the compiled-nature... so you not only get type-safety and intellisense, but you can get the perf benefit as well.

The drawback that I see is that it's so flippin' verbose.  I converted an app to NVelocity and was astounded at how clean it looked.  The problem is that there were a lot of things that didn't work with NVelocity (like your own custom view helpers) and there was a severe lack of documentation.

I added a feature to MvcContrib where you can register your own HtmlExtension types to it, but it's more of a bandaid until a better solution comes out.

Answer (score 1):

I've used NVelocity in the past. For the most part it makes the code really clean and simple to follow; however, it normally ends up just being a few ViewData variables which have been filled up by XSLT files before hand. So I guess really my View Engine would be both XSLT (which is a love/hate thing - Extension Methods make it really useful) and NVelocity.

Answer (score 0):

I've used NVelocity with MonoRail for some time but have recently switched to [Spark](http://dev.dejardin.org) for both Asp.Net MVC and MonoRail. The syntax seems very natural to me, but I guess that's to be expected. ;)